# Dimensional Modeling: how to create a table without Surrogate Primary Keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

From what I have understand, we don't have Primary Key in the fact table and put a Surrogate Key is somehow a waste of space. Hence, the foreign key combination is the primary key for the fact table.

But I may case, I was not able to do that because the unique keys can potentially repeat in the fact table, e.g. same person paid twice on the same day, in same restaurant. In this cas, the primary key is no longer unique...

Is there anyway to solve this problème, without adding a surrogate key?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This just sounds like a transaction table, not a fact table.  And in a transaction table, you should have the time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have a time dimension but what if it's at the same time?

Comment: . . Fact tables contain summaries of things that share dimension values.  There should not be duplicates.  If you don't want summaries then it isn't a fact table.  If you want a transaction table, then you should still have *some* attribute that distinguishes them.  If not time, then cashier or something.

Comment: @NicolasTang - the question you should ask is "how do I distinguish legitimate multiple occurrences from duplicates?". It's an ETL problem, not a table design problem. If you can be sure that these are valid records, you don't need them to be unique. (side note: In general, you should never have primary keys in your fact tables - only in dimensions).

Comment: @GordonLinoff A fact table can and often is used to measure transactions: a transactional fact is the most dimensional & most additive kind, where each row is a measurement event. They're not just for summaries.

Comment: @Rich . . . Whether a "transactional" fact table is a fact table or not is really a matter of opinion (and I get to opine because I've written books on databases).  I don't think it is useful to include them, because fact tables with summaries are quite powerful constructs and I don't find it useful to confuse the definition.

Comment: We all get to opine whether we have written a book or not. I tend to go with Kimball on the definitions for dimensional modelling concepts like fact tables, it’s less confusing that way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I find it confusing to ever consider a "Fact" table to be a "Summary".  I prefer to see Fact table(s) as containing the raw data only.  Based on what you are saying, all Summary tables are Fact tables?  In which case, simply call them "Tables"; I would rather keep "Fact" to have some distinction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a table like this a primary key or unique key combination is strongly recommended but if you are avoiding adding PK you may want to add unique transaction numbers so that you can do a combination of customer number and transaction number as the key combo.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB, if you don't provide a PK, will provide one for you.  But it is 6 bytes and hidden.  Compared to a 4-byte surrogate `INT`, this is bigger!

Check the data; there may be a "natural" PK that is a column or combination of columns.

Generally, for DW, the only index I have on the Fact table is the PK.  Then I use "Summary tables" for the bulk of accesses.  These are smaller and faster.  In an extreme case, I will purge old Fact rows (via `DROP PARTITION`) but hang onto the Summary tables 'forever'.  This keeps the disk space in check, while losing virtually nothing useful of the data.

Bottom line:  Provide an *explicit* PK for every table.